# UiApp button rollover setStyleAttribute

Tags: google-apps-script

In UiApp is there a simple way to change the setStyleAttribute when the mouse is over a button.  Basically I would like to create a rollover button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and it's somewhat simple.

You have to create two client handlers, one to set the styles on hover and another to set it back. Then add them to the button, like this:

```js
var btn = app.createButton('Button').setStyleAttributes({color:'blue'});
var setStyleHover = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setStyleAttributes({color:'red'});
var setStyleBack = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setStyleAttributes({color:'blue'});
btn.addMouseOverHandler(setStyleHover);
btn.addMouseOutHandler(setStyleBack);
//add button to your interface
//show app
```

Comment: That works out nicely.  I was thinking I had to pass it through a function just to make it change.  Thank you.